# How to reproduce this dark-toned color effect?

Tags: post-processing, color, reverse-engineering, effect

What technique is used in this image to produce such colors?

Is it just saturation and hue adjustment?

[image: Runaway, by Omair Haq]

Comment: You might get better results with this question if you can describe the effect in words.

Comment: Could you put the image in your question? (You download the image first if it's not yours)

Comment: If it's not yours, make sure you get permission before re-uploading here. If you don't have that permission, linking is the most polite.

Comment: Permission has been granted; see below.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took that picture a few years ago so I don't exactly remember. My usual technique when i used to have photoshop was to start off with the auto adjusts, and then messing around with the curves with no goal in mind. I would just try random things and see which combinations I liked best. Also, for this picture I desaturated it a little bit and added a vignette (which i think is too strong now). Also I took the shot with sunset light which contributed to the golden colors. Rookie editing Now I use Adobe Lightroom and I like it a lot better because its very easy to use.

Comment: Welcome, Omair! Would you be willing to explain as an answer here? That way, it benefits everyone, not just Paolo?

Comment: (And, do you mind if the image is linked inline into the question?)

Comment: Cool. Hope you stick around the site!

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of run-on sentences. Could you give a little more details? "messing around with the curves...", "I would just try random things...", "...I desaturated it little", "added a vignette", "no goal in mind...""Also I took the shot with sunset light". Just a few more details please???

Comment: THanks for asnwering, for sure you are the best source :) Actually it would be nice to have some information on curves: color space used, what shape had the curves: S shape, concave or convex, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Photo has a vignette and little sepia effect I believe. I believe also that WB setting is set to cloudy cause it has this yellowish feeling. I believe that red is desaturated a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important step is with the exposure. The image here has some nice mid to shadow areas to play with, punctuated by a few intense highlights, this also makes most of the image subdued except for the orange and yellow pop of the roses.

After that to my eyes...

There appears to be a moderate amount of contrast, I'm not seeing too many crushed blacks and only a few blown highlights.

Obviously a yellow cast has been added, either by white balance or a color overlay. Saturation seems somewhat high, you can see some of the color of the bench being over-saturated on the left.

I think a good amount of sharpness has been added, possibly by local contrast enhancement (clarity) / highpass sharpening.

Finally, a lot of vignetting has been added, which darkens the edges of the image to focus the image on the subject.

Overall, it's a nice, carefully crafted image.